# How cost function of Logistic Regression is derived?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, mathematical-statistics, sigmoid-curve

How the cost function of logistic regression given below is derived ?

[image: Cost function]

Here Sigmoid function is used for logistic regression.

***After heavy search on internet i have come up here to put on my question , no other question on this portal talks about it so please don't mark it as duplicate.***

Comment: it's an entropy

Comment: Hi Abhishek, the links I've added should answer your question completely. If you're still stuck after reading them, please edit your question to explain what you understand and where you're stuck and we can help you get unstuck.